# AIX server DOD method for secure erase disk

Tags: linux, shell, aix

I would like to know how can i securely erase disk on AIX as per DOD standards?
any utility i can download and use on aix server

rather using regular dd or diag command?
Appreciate your help!

Regards,
Adel